# Как сделать чтобы Спрайт поворачивался к мышке?

Tags: python, pygame, спрайт

программирую игру на pygame. Решил сделать так, чтобы спрайт все время поворачивался к курсору мыши. Вот только как это сделать не знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно посчитать вектор от вашего персонажа до позиции курсора. Это можно сделать через вычитание позиции игрока и мыши:

```
mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
rel_x, rel_y = mouse_x - self.x, mouse_y - self.y
```

Затем можно посчитать угол:

```
angle = math.atan2(rel_y, rel_x)
```

Это вернет величину угла в радианах, а функции `pygame.transform.rotate(surface, angle)` требуется величина в градусах. 
Она также вычислит угол в другом направлении(против часовой стрелки), поэтому вам нужно просто добавить/отнять 90 или 180 градусов и изображение станет правильным:

```
angle = (180 / math.pi) * -math.atan2(rel_y, rel_x)
```

После поворота вам нужно изменить положение прямоугольника:

```
self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, int(angle))
self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.position)
```

Обратите внимание, что я вращаю атрибут с именем self.original_image. При применении поворота к изображению оно может слегка искажаться.

Весь код:

```
import math

def rotate(self):
    mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    rel_x, rel_y = mouse_x - self.x, mouse_y - self.y
    angle = (180 / math.pi) * -math.atan2(rel_y, rel_x)
    self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, int(angle))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.position)
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Вам понадобится уравнение нормали вашего спрайта (выберите линию,  или отрезок, характеризующую "лицо" вашего спрайта и постойте к ней нормаль), а также линия между серединой этого "лица" и координатами курсора мыши. Теперь просто определяете угол между этими линиями и доворачиваете на него свой объект

Comment: а как угол в pygame определить?

Comment: Угол между двумя отрезками, или прямыми. Погуглите формулы они не сложные